# Show $\left(X-m_{X}\right)-A\left(Y-m_{Y}\right)$ and $Y$ are Uncorrelated Given $AC_{Y}=C_{XY}$

Tags: probability, correlation

I'm given the facts that $X$, $Y$ are jointly normal random vectors and the matrix $A$ solves $AC_{Y}=C_{XY}$, where $C_{Y}$ is the correlation matrix for $Y$ and $C_{XY}$ is the cross-correlation matrix between $X$ and $Y$. I try to proceed by computing the correlation matrix

$$
\begin{align}
  \text{Corr}\left(\left(X-m_{X}\right)-A\left(Y-m_{Y}\right),Y\right)
  &=E[{\left(\left(X-m_{X}\right)-A\left(Y-m_{Y}\right)\right)Y^{\intercal}} ]\\
  &=E[{XY^{\intercal}-m_{X}Y^{\intercal}-AYY^{\intercal}+Am_{Y}Y^{\intercal}}] \\
  &=E[{XY^{\intercal}}]-m_{X}E[{Y^{\intercal}}]-AE[{YY^{\intercal}}]+Am_{Y}E[{Y^{\intercal}}] \\
  &=C_{XY}-m_{X}E[{Y^{\intercal}}]-AC_{Y}+Am_{Y}E{Y^{\intercal}} \\
  &=\left(-m_{X}+Am_{Y}\right)m_{Y}^{\intercal} 
\end{align}
$$

After this step I don't really know how to proceed. I think I would have to prove that $-m_{X}+Am_{Y}=0$ but I'm not sure how to go about showing that.

Comment: You said "correlation" but in the first line of your equation block, you're computing covariance. Which is it?

Comment: I com computing the correlation matrix between two random vectors: $\left(X-m_{X}\right)-A\left(Y-m_{Y}\right)$ and $Y$

Comment: That's not how you compute "correlation." Take the case when $X$ and $Y$ are scalar, for example. Your formula should still work then, but it doesn't.

Comment: I guess I should disclose that this is part of a problem found in Gubner (Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers ) Chapter 9 Problem 17.

Comment: That's okay but you're computing "covariance" whereas you're talking "correlation." Do you see that?

Comment: @yurnero For two random vectors $U$ and $V$, uncorrelatedness is checking if $E[UV^{\intercal}]=E[U]E[V]^{\intercal}$, right?

Comment: If you want correlation, you need to rescale each element of the covariance matrix by the product of the corresponding standard deviations. Again, think how you would compute covariance and correlation between 2 *scalar* random variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91980/discussion-between-segfault-and-yurnero).

Comment: There is nothing to continue. You're making a simple mistake. I'm not trying to be mean but it is what it is. Write down the formulas for covariance and correlation between 2 scalar random variables. Contrast those with what you're doing here.

Comment: For two random variables, the covariance is defined $E[(X-E[X])(Y-E(Y))]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. The first term (on the left) is covariance. The first term on the right is what I've been calling correlation. The second term on the right is just the product of the expectations. If $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, then the first term on the left is zero and we have $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.

Comment: Then your definition of "correlation" is wrong, at least in English, and this explains the errors in your post. Look up how it is defined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C_Y$ and $C_{XY}$ indeed are "correlation" and "cross-correlation" matrices as written in the OP, the claim is false.

For example, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are scalar, with mean $0$ each, variances $4$ and $9$, respectively, and covariance $2$ between them. Then:
$$
C_Y=1 \text{ (always}),\quad C_{XY}=\frac{2}{2\times 3}=\frac{1}{3},\quad A=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
So with $Z\equiv (X-0)-\frac{1}{3}(Y-0)=X-\frac{1}{3}Y$, the covariance between $Z$ and $Y$ is
$$
E(ZY)-E(Z)E(Y)=E(ZY)=E(XY)-\frac{1}{3}E(Y^2)=2-\frac{9}{3}\neq 0.
$$

On the other hand, if $C_Y$ and $C_{XY}$ were "covariance" and "cross-covariance" matrices, then problem is straightforward:
$$
\operatorname{Cov}[(X-m_X)-A(Y-m_Y),Y]=\underbrace{\operatorname{Cov}[X-m_X,Y]}_{C_{XY}}-A\underbrace{\operatorname{Cov}[Y-m_Y,Y]}_{C_Y}=0.
$$